# Does Entity Framework Code First allow for fluent mappings in separate files?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent-interface

I am developing a rather large database schema using Entity Framework Code First.  I prefer the Fluent API over the Data Annotations approach, as it leaves my domain objects as simple POCOs.

In order to use Fluent API, I have to override OnModelCreating in the class that inherits from DbContext.

I don't like that all mappings for all of my entities are in this one method.  I have used things like FluentNHibernate before, where each entity has it's own mapping class.  Does EF have anything similar?

I suppose I could create my own interface to implement a mapping class and call them all within the OnModelCreating method.  I could use reflection or an IoC to discover them all.  I don't particularly see anything wrong with this approach, but I was wondering if Entity Framework already comes with something like this out of the box?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can create one configuration class per entity derived from `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` and put these classes into separate files. In your derived `DbContext` you add instances of those configuration classes to the model builder. Example:

```
public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(u => u.UserName);

        Property(u => u.UserName)
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        // etc.
    }
}

public class RoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Role>
{
    public RoleConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(r => r.RoleName);

        // etc.
    }
}
```

Derived context:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    //...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleConfiguration());
    }
}
```

There is also a `ComplexTypeConfiguration<T>` you can derive from to configure complex types.

Comment: It almost necessary when dealing with large complex models. Otherwise you have to put it all into one OnModelCreating method.